# Get the date format of dates stored as varchar in DB?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fix some dates (historical data) in my DB. I would like to pull these strings and then convert them to a particular format.

The thing is that not all the dates are stored in the db in the same format, and therefore an error is at times thrown even though they pass the ISDATE() function to validate that they are actually dates.

So for example when I try the following, case 1 results in error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' however case 2 works just fine.

CASE 1

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(varchar(25),CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2001 00:00:00', 120),103)+' 00:00:00'
```

CASE 2

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(varchar(25),CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/01 00:00:00', 120),103)+' 00:00:00'
```

Notice the difference that in case one the year is 2001 and in case to its 01.

So is there a function that can determine the date format so I can convert accordingly in each case or do you know of a simpler solution to this issue?

Comment: You need to know saved format. Otherwise your dates won't be accurate even if you manage to convert them. For ex; `11/10/2011` can be `10th of November` Or `11th of October`.

Comment: let me the exact data type in which those dates stored in table

Comment: The dates are stored as varchar. I mentioned that in the title of the question